# How to inject IOrchardServices to Handler in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I want to inject `IOrchardServices` into `Handler` because of i need some service in handler,so in my handler i wrote this:

```
public class EstatePartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices Services;
    public EstatePartHandler(IOrchardServices services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }
...
}
```

But `Orchard` throws an exception on construction the handler:

```
Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'Estate.Handlers.EstatePartHandler'. Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell for sure because you haven't posted all the code, but it sounds like you have two constructors on your handler - one taking IOrchardServices and another taking a different dependency. Merge your constructors into one method, taking two dependencies:

```
public class EstatePartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices Services;
    public EstatePartHandler(IOrchardServices services, IAnotherDependency another)
    {
        Services = services;
        Another = another;
    }
...
}
```

If this is not the case, please post the full code for your handler.